# ASP.NET Core Remote Validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I am working through a tutorial on ASP.NET Core and this is the first time I have used remote validation.  I have double checked my code and did a lot of searching online and from all the examples I have seen and tried, I still get the same result.  I keep getting a 404 not found error for the validation method and I cannot figure out why. Here is my code.

In my layout view, here are files I am importing.

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha256-sPB0F50YUDK0otDnsfNHawYmA5M0pjjUf4TvRJkGFrI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" integrity="sha256-XNNC8ESw29iopRLukVRazlP44TxnjGmEQanHJ5kHmtk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is my ViewModel.

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Remote("IsEmailInUse", "AccountController")]
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally the controller.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = model.Email,
                    Email = model.Email
                };

                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                }

                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                    }
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Login Attempt");
            }
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> IsEmailInUse(string email)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return Json(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json($"Email {email} is already in use.");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ControllerName in `Remote` attribute is incorrect ,change it like below:

```
 [Remote("IsEmailInUse", "Account")]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was something obvious but just wasn't seeing it.